OpenAPI - Could not resolve reference: Failed to fetch - from json
Swagger Editor throws an error, after searching similar issues, read documentation, googling... i cant get correct result, can you help me please? Thanks
Resolver error at paths./create.post.parameters.0.schema.$ref
Could not resolve reference: Failed to fetch
Jump to line 12
YAML file
openapi: 3.0.3

info:
  title: Test API
  version: 1.0.1
  
paths:
  /create:
    post:
      parameters:
        # headers
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/TestName'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success response
          content:
            text/plain:
              schema:
                type: string
                example: pong
components:
  parameters:
    TestName:
      name: TestName
      in: header
      required: true
      example: 'Test'
      schema:
        $ref: ./common/CommonTypes.json#/%24defs/TName

JSON file
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
    "description": "common",
    "version": "1.1",
    "$defs": {
        "TName": {
            "type": "string",
            "maxLength": 50
        }
    }
}


You don't need to encode relative refs.
this should be sufficient, assuming CommonTypes.json is located in the same folder as the openapi.json file.
schema:
        $ref: ./common/CommonTypes.json#/definitions/TName


The only other change is the $schema value should be updated, but you should know that OpenAPI 3.0.x does not support JSON Schema 2020-12. It only supports a subset of JSON Schema draft-04.
the keyword $defs was originally definitions
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "description": "common",
    "version": "1.1",
    "definitions": {
        "TName": {
            "type": "string",
            "maxLength": 50
        }
    }
}

